# create tar with multiple directories and file locations

Tags: linux, centos, tar

I have some scripts and files located in various locations like:

- `/etc/dir1`
- `/var/www/html`
- `/home/somedir`

I want to make a tar file so that it copies files and folders with the location structure. When I untar to another location, all the files will be copied to their respective locations in the correct paths; same as where tar was made.

Comment: Similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178189/compressing-multiple-files-in-different-folders-without-folder-structure

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You can just use

```
tar -cf myfile.tar /etc/dir1 /var/www/html /home/somedir
```

also, you could use

```
tar -czf myfile.tar.gz /etc/dir1 /var/www/html /home/somedir
```

This second example  (*note the z in the -czf parameter*) will compress the tar file using  g(z)ip.

Comment: switch c to x when you want to extract.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me
small change by adding "change to directory DIR (C)" argument

```
tar -zcvf myfile.tar -C /etc/dir1 /var/www/html /home/somedir
```